# Sonar SQLException when starting tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat, sonarqube

I have been trying to install a new version of Sonar, however after this did not work (due to a table_lock error with the database migration) I have referred back to the original version 2.11. Now when I start tomcat I get this exception (attached). I have been changing the my.cnf and some things may have been reset.

In the catalina.out log I get this error:

```
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' (using       password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4004) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Sonar database no longer has access granted for the sonar user. To fix it, type "mysql" from a command prompt and do the following:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON your_sonar_database TO 'sonar@localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_sonar_user';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```

Then restart the Sonar server and you should be good.